# Does Karma coexist with Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

From the online definition:

**Karma:** is a tool which spawns a web server that executes source code against test code for each of the browsers connected. The results of each test against each browser are examined and displayed via the command line to the developer.

**Jasmine**: is a development framework for testing js code. It does not depend on any other JavaScript frameworks. It does not require a DOM. And it has a clean, obvious syntax so that you can easily write tests.

My question is, does Karma require Jasmine to run, does Karma depend on Jasmine since Jasmine is a framework and Karma is a tool which runs on that framework and runs the written tests?

I'm using both of them with my angular2 project.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/testing#tools-and-technologies Just read this.

Comment: So the answer to my question is yes? Karma really does depend on Jasmine?and can not go without it?

Comment: Yes the answer is yes. Jasmine does **It ships with an HTML test runner that executes tests in the browser.** Karma use this browser to show results. Or you totally need to rewrite karma so that it show the output of the console only.

Comment: You can post that as an answer if you wish to gain points. I got it now

Comment: Nah it's fine I'm here to help not to gain points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Karma is client-side test runner and doesn't depend on Jasmine. It can run without any testing framework at all.

It has plugins for major testing frameworks, including [Jasmine](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-jasmine) and [Mocha](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-mocha).

Comment: Then why do I need Jasmine for? Why is Jasmine integrated in angular2 projects?

Comment: Angular is application framework. Jasmine is testing framework. If you don't use one of them, you end up recreating its functionality with vanilla JS. In case of Jasmine this means that `if (foo !== 1) throw new Error('foo not equal to 1')` will be used instead of `it(..., () => expect(foo).toBe(1) })`. All [Jasmine API](http://jasmine.github.io/edge/introduction.html) will be unavailable. No `describe`, `it` or `beforeEach` blocks. No assertions, no spies.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Jasmine and Karma can co-exist.

- Jasmine is a javascript based framework that we use to write unit
  test cases. Alternative to jasmine is Mocha.
- Karma is a test runner, which runs unit test cases on browser. And It can be used with all type of unit test frameworks. And It's easy to integrate with all CI tools like Bamboo and Jenkins.